# Conditional regex match groups in text input stream with Java, disregard ill-formed lines

Tags: java, regex

Having practised with a [regex tester](http://regex-testdrive.com/en/dotest), I found that the following pattern `[a-zA-Z+[^ \t]+0-9]`, was able to match the groups that I'm interested in:

[image]

I've tried to "Java-ify" it as follows: `Pattern.compile("(a-zA-Z)( \t)(0-9)");`, not exactly sure if that's the right way... but more on this later.

My input stream looks like this:

```
#### LOGS ####
CONSOLE:
makePush            2196
makePush            638
makePush            470
opAdd           8342
opAdd           288
opStop          133
0x
DEBUG:
#### TRACE ####
PUSH32          pc=00000000 gas=10000000000 cost=3

PUSH32          pc=00000033 gas=9999999997 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

PUSH32          pc=00000066 gas=9999999994 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
00000001  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

ADD             pc=00000099 gas=9999999991 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
00000001  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
00000002  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

ADD             pc=00000100 gas=9999999988 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
00000001  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

STOP            pc=00000101 gas=9999999985 cost=0
Stack:
00000000  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f
```

So not only do I want to match the two different parts of the lines that come before and after the large white space (*actually three consecutive tabs*), but I also want to **ignore** every line that doesn't fit that pattern, i.e. "`some alphabetic characters`", "`big white space`", "`few numbers`".

I've tried to do it like this:

```
for (String k : debugOutput) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(a-zA-Z)( \t)(0-9)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(k);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("group 2: " + matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("group 3: " + matcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work- it doesn't pick up the groups that I want, and it doesn't ignore the lines that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Can you show more of the code around the pattern part? How do you read the file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/6f6c75f44fc91a433b4a9b0db57b104a it's a bit convoluted- because its a hadoop job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the pattern to :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)(\\s+)([0-9]+)");
```

Then if an input line equals

```
String input = "makePush            2196";
```

it prints

```
group 1: makePush
group 2:             
group 3: 2196
```

Comment: and it will ignore the other lines?

Comment: @s.matthew.english yes, because they don't match the pattern.

Comment: I don't know why- but for me this isn't working- it doesn't even enter the loop based on the conditional matcher

Comment: @s.matthew.english in the gist you've shared, the pattern does not equal mine. You are missing the `+` symbols.

Comment: no- I had it there- I just took it out for some experiement- when I tested it- it was in there, that's just the full file- for context and so on

Comment: @s.matthew.english can you confirm that `debugOutput` contains anything? I see you're using STDERR to fill it, which is different from STDIN.

Comment: yes- I'm certain it has content- when I tried with `(.)` it was a hit. Just attempted again with this `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z])([ \t])([0-9])");`, because that works on the tester site- but... also didn't work in my java code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155775/discussion-between-luciano-van-der-veekens-and-s-matthew-english).